# How to position hole in an arrow in xypic

Tags: xy-pic

trying to draw a 3D commutative diagram here and getting really stuck trying to get the hole in one of the arrows in the right place, you should see which one I mean as there is only one crossover.

Here is my code:

```
\xymatrix{
        &               &       &       &T(U_1 \cap U_2) \ar[ddr]^{(\sigma_2)_*} \ar[ddl]_{(\sigma_1)_*}    &       \\ 
        &U_1 \cap U_2 \ar[ddr]^{\sigma_2} |!{[dd];[rr]}\hole \ar[ddl]_{\sigma_1} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &        &       &                   &       \\
        &               &       &T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \ar[rr]^{\textit{bundle transition}} & & T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \\
\CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar[rr]_{\textit{coordinate transition}} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D & & \CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &            &   & \\}
```

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, if anyone can suggest any other ways to make this diagram look `more 3D' I would be very grateful.

Thanks, Adam.

Comment: MikTex doesn support xy-pic, and xypdf doesn't support \xymatrix.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Really? I don't think so.

Comment: @egreg  Well, the package manager couldn't find xy-pic.  Perhaps they use another name.

Comment: @JohnKormylo http://miktex.org/packages/xypic

Comment: @egreg Found it. I had to sychronize the package database, then discovered I already had it installed (xypic not xy-pic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd give a try to `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=1em]
&&&& T(U_1\cap U_2) \arrow[ddl,swap,"(\sigma_1)_*"] \arrow[ddr,"(\sigma_2)_*"] \\
& U_1\cap U_2 \arrow[ddl,swap,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[urrr,dashed,"D"] \\
&&& T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}) \arrow[rr,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{bundle transition}"] &&
    T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}) \\
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[urrr,dashed,"D"] 
                         \arrow[rr,swap,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{coordinate transition}"] &&
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[urrr,dashed,"D"]
  \arrow[uul,leftarrow,crossing over,"\sigma_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The trick is to draw the crossing over arrow later than the arrow it has to be crossed over (reversing the direction with `leftarrow`).

[image]

If you want the left triangle to be in the background, just change the arrow that must cross over:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=1em]
&&&& T(U_1\cap U_2) \arrow[ddl,swap,"(\sigma_1)_*"] \arrow[ddr,"(\sigma_2)_*"] \\
& U_1\cap U_2 \arrow[ddl,swap,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[ddr,"\sigma_2"]
              \arrow[urrr,dashed,"D"] \\
&&& T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}) \arrow[rr,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{bundle transition}"] &&
    T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}) \\
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[urrr,dashed,crossing over,"D"] 
                         \arrow[rr,swap,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{coordinate transition}"] &&
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[urrr,dashed,"D"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative form where it may be easier to guess the 3D aspect, with the bigger triangle in front.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=1em]
& U_1\cap U_2 \arrow[ddl,swap,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[ddr,"\sigma_2"]
              \arrow[drrr,dashed,"D"] \\
&&&& T(U_1\cap U_2) \arrow[ddr,"(\sigma_2)_*"] \\
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[drrr,dashed,"D"] 
                         \arrow[rr,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{coordinate transition}"] &&
\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \arrow[drrr,dashed,"D"] \\
&&& T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}) 
    \arrow[rr,swap,"\scriptscriptstyle\textit{bundle transition}"]
    \arrow[uur,leftarrow,crossing over,"(\sigma_1)_*"]  &&
    T(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get the dashed arrow crossing over?

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson Yes, of course: added.

Comment: cheers, might start using tikz :)

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson -- with the dashed arrow crossing over "in front", this looks not so much like 3d, but like one of m.c.escher's "impossible constructions".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Probably the background triangle should be higher than the “T-transformed” one.

Comment: @barberabeeton I get what you mean, the reason I thought it should look like that was because the right hand triangle seems bigger and so should be closer towards us. Probably the reason it doesn't look right to put the arrow crossing over is that I would need to slant the right hand triangle to make it look like viewed at an angle. No idea how to do that though!

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson I added a different format that might be easier to read.

Comment: @egreg thanks I'm going to use that last one in my document it does look nicest. you rock!

Comment: may I also ask, are you using a different font to me? your letters seem to look nicer!

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson It's standard Computer Modern

Comment: ah!  with the larger triangle lower, the perspective is more obvious.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I, too, would opt for `tikz-cd`.

Anyway, this is a solution with `xy-pic`. Note that it works only with the latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf route.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips,all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
        &               &       &       &T(U_1 \cap U_2) \ar[ddr]^{(\sigma_2)_*} \ar[ddl]_{(\sigma_1)_*}    &       \\
        &U_1 \cap U_2 \ar[ddl]_{\sigma_1} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &        &       &                   &       \\
        &               &       &T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \ar[rr]^{\textit{bundle transition}} & & T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \\
\CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar[rr]_{\textit{coordinate transition}} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D & & 
\CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar@*{[|(15)][white]}[uul]\ar@{<-}[uul]_{\sigma_2}\ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &   &   & \\}
\]

\[
\xymatrix{
        &               &       &       &T(U_1 \cap U_2) \ar[ddr]^{(\sigma_2)_*} \ar[ddl]_{(\sigma_1)_*}    &       \\
        &U_1 \cap U_2 \ar[ddr]^{\sigma_2} \ar[ddl]_{\sigma_1} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &        &       &                   &       \\
        &               &       &T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \ar[rr]^{\textit{bundle transition}} & & T(\CC \setminus \{ 0\}) \\
\CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar[rr]_{\textit{coordinate transition}} \ar@*{[|(15)][white]}[urrr]\ar@{-->}[urrr]^D & & 
\CC \setminus \{ 0\} \ar@{-->}[urrr]^D &   &   & \\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main idea is to draw a thicker white arrow over the underlying arrow, for example

```
\ar@*{[|(15)][white]}[urrr]
```

and then the visible arrow over that

```
\ar@{-->}[urrr]^D
```

Answer (score 1):

The "break" command in your code (`|!{[dd];[rr]}\hole`) should instead be `|!{[ddl];[rrd]}\hole`, since you were hoping to "slide" along with last drawn line to the position where it intersects with another line(`!` command).

The `[ddl];[rrd]` part specifies the the start and end of the line that recently-drawn line intersects with: The start of the line is `d`own, `d`own, `l`eft from current cell, the end is `r`ight, `r`ight, `d`own from current cell.

And finally, ask xy pic to place a `\hole` at the position with
xymatrix extension command `|`(break).